# How to convert simple CSS into makeStyles for React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to convert simple CSS into makeStyles for React?

I have added style to the TextField to make it stretchable vertically, by using the attribute `resize`. It is working, actually. Below is the original code I have that I need to refactor.

```
<div className="mb-4 stretchable">
  <style>{"\
    .stretchable textarea{\
      resize:vertical;\
    }\
  "}
  </style>
  <TextField
    multiline
    label="取材メモ"
    className={classes.meetingLogContent}
    rows={8}
    name='content'
    value={meetingLogData.content}
    onChange={handleChange}
    variant="outlined"
    fullWidth
  />
</div>
```

It is just that our client wanted the `style` I added to be converted into `makeStyle`. And it could not target the TextField and does not make it **stretchable**.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  meetingLogContent: {
    resize: 'vertical',
  },
}))
```

After that I instantiated it into classes.

```
const classes = useStyles()
```

And applied the newly instantiated variable to the textfield.

```
<TextField className={classes.meetingLogContent} />
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this is exactly how to use makeStyles and useStyles. what problems are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply `resize` to a `div` that contains `TextArea` and not to the `TextArea` itself. Something like:

```
 <div className={classes.meetingLogContent}>
   <TextField
     multiline
     label="取材メモ"
     rows={8}
     name='content'
     value={meetingLogData.content}
     onChange={handleChange}
     variant="outlined"
     fullWidth
   />
 </div>
```

Then your useStyles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  meetingLogContent: {
    resize: 'vertical',
    overflow: 'auto'   //<-- don't forget overflow to auto
  },
}))
```

The result is:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-custom-textfield-overrides-forked-u2xvq?file=/src/Demo.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: Great, it solved my problem. But is there a way to make the rows value dynamic each time the browser is minimized or maximised? Because as you have observed, the row of my TextField is statically set to the value of 8. Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @NicoNisaw if you want to change number of rows based on browser width you could use `withWidth` and `isWidthUp` (I mean MUI [breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/)). if you want to change number of rows based on browser height is more tricky. You could take browser height using `useRef` (something like [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15662#issuecomment-741650303) but here he is taking button height) and then dynamically change number of rows based on value of height you got from ref.